# How to implement OAuth 2.0 Authorization Code Grant from Single-Page Application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, oauth-2.0, owin

We have an Angular SPA backed by an ASP.NET Web API that uses the OAuth 2.0 [Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3) with a Bearer Token for authorisation. The API uses Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth to implement OAuth.

We're trying to integrate with a third-party application that will use the [Authorization Code Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1) so users can authorise it to access our application on their behalf.

We want the authorisation page to be a part of the SPA, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to submit the authorisation request from the SPA to the API and have it redirect back to the third-party application.

I've tried using both AJAX (like all the other API requests in the SPA) and a regular HTML form (so that redirect responses redirect the page).

We were originally sending back a JSON response from the API and letting the SPA do the redirection itself, but OWIN will automatically send a redirect response if there's some error; so there doesn't appear to be any way to avoid redirect responses.

If I send the request via AJAX, the browser will automatically follow the redirect responses sent by the server by sending another AJAX request instead of redirecting the page.

If I use a regular HTML form to send the request, there doesn't seem to be any way to send the required `Authorization` header with the Bearer Token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a HTML form and sending the current access token in the form body. I created a hidden input in the form for the access token and only set its value when the form was being submitted (to reduce the chance of it being seen by the user or a malicious script/extension).

On the server side, our OAuth code was previously only looking for the access token in the `Authorization` header; I changed it to also look in the request form (`IOwinRequest.ReadFormAsync`) for authorization code requests.

The OAuth code now sends a redirect response to a successful authorization code request instead of sending a JSON response with the redirect URI.